# SQL Collation mismatching issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, vbscript, powerdesigner

Have some collation(?) troubles when getting data from ADODB.RecordSet.
When selecting with SQL Management studio everything looks fine like

```
PriceMonitoring Справочник конкурентов2_Temp    Table   6142061 dbo
```

Buuut, when i get data from powerdesigner's vbscript i got table names mismatching like

```
Table
    Not in Model    dbo.Ni?aai?iee eiieo?aioia2_Temp
    Not in DB       dbo.Справочник конкурентов2_Temp
```

For this moment i've already tried to specify different collations (COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, Cyrillic_General_CI_AS, Ukrainian_CI_AS) in my sql script. I even changed DB collation, that doesn't help and had no effect to result. Any ideas, community?

That is a part of sql script.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
USE DB_Control
SELECT ds.*, isnull(upo.Object_Name,'') as Object_Name_Updated, isnull(tuo.Object_Name,'') as Object_Name_Uncontrol 
FROM 
    -- 
    dbo.Design_Checksum AS ds 
    -- 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Uncontrolled_Object AS uo 
    ON  uo.DB_Name          = ds.DB_Name 
    AND uo.Object_Type_ID   = ds.Object_Type_ID 
    AND uo.Schema_Name      = ds.Schema_Name 
    AND uo.Object_Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS     = ds.Object_Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    -- 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Updated_Object AS upo 
    ON  upo.DB_Name         = ds.DB_Name 
    AND upo.Object_Type_ID  = ds.Object_Type_ID 
    AND upo.Schema_Name     = ds.Schema_Name 
    AND upo.Object_Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    = ds.Object_Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    -- 
    LEFT JOIN PD.Test_Uncontrolled_Object AS tuo 
    ON  tuo.DB_Name         = ds.DB_Name 
    AND tuo.Object_Type_ID  = ds.Object_Type_ID 
    AND tuo.Schema_Name     = ds.Schema_Name 
    AND tuo.Object_Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    = ds.Object_Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    AND (tuo.Date_End IS NULL 
       OR tuo.Date_End > GETDATE()) 
WHERE  
    ds.DB_Name = 'PriceMonitoring'  
    AND uo.Object_Name IS NULL 
ORDER BY  
    UPPER(REPLACE(ds.Object_Type_ID, '_', '!')),  
    UPPER(REPLACE(ds.Schema_Name, '_', '!')),  
    UPPER(REPLACE(ds.Object_Name, '_', '!'))
```

Comment: Please show the rest of the query. The join is obviously working fine, but I suspect something is wrong in the SELECT... you should also validate that this PowerDesigner and VBScript you are using actually support Unicode...

Comment: Well, it's not just cyrillic problem, the strange thing is in mismatching `dbo.UpdateNearestCompetitors` and `dbo.UpdateNearestNompetitors` ! I'm sure, that 'C' in "Competitor" is from latin. I checked it twice

Comment: Please populate some sample data on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). It's impossible to reverse engineer your code to understand what data you have and why you're getting what you think are incorrect matches.

Comment: Also, that N is *output*, not what it matched on originally. Again, please post a repro that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I cant demonstrate it in fiddle the problem based on powerdesigner to sql, not sql itself. I thought may this kind of problem 'C'->'N' and 'Ni?' -> 'Спр' has some kind of signature and maybe someone know what is the point of problem

Comment: Well, sorry, I can't help then. I can barely spell powerdesigner. Have you validated that they even support displaying Unicode data?

Comment: They do, but now I know not with ADODB